# Как узнать текст после курсора ввода в Text Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите, как узнать текст после курсора ввода (|) в Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать специальные текстовые индексы (см. [Text widget indices](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html)), в данном случае `INSERT` (индекс положения курсора) и `END` (конец текста):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()


def on_button():
    label.config(text=text.get(tk.INSERT, tk.END))


tk.Button(root, text="Press me", command=on_button).pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]